# Does anyone know any specific words that can be used to describe a character flying?

Tags: creative-writing, word-choice, description

I feel like I've used words like "floating" and "hovering" too often, to the point of tedium.

Comment: for specific words https://english.stackexchange.com may be more appropriate, however if your problem is about showing a character flying without just saying 'the character is flying', this is the right place and you should rephrase your question. Don't forget to mention what you tried and why that did not satisfy you.

Comment: A [thesaurus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/fly) is your friend here, and you can also look up the synonyms to get even more possible words.

Comment: Depends on a specific style of character's flying. "That wasn't flying. That was falling with style." (c)

Answer (score 1):

Defying gravity, perhaps. Immune to gravity.

Suspended, without support.

Weightless in the air.

As general advice, use more words; use metaphors and similes; readers do not mind reading.

She's three feet above the ground, cruising along beside me.

Also, recognize that both characters and the reader will grow accustomed to a character that is routinely flying, so you don't have to describe this so often. Readers will get bored by the repetition, just like you do. Let the fact be told by dialogue or body action.

> Darcy looked up at Sheila, squinting into the sun behind her. "I wish
> you wouldn't fly so high, it's hard to talk to you up there."
>
> Sheila dropped down to eye level with Darcy. "Sorry, earlier I was
> trying to find that bend, and I just forgot."

We do want to describe surroundings and such, but we don't want to get so repetitive about descriptions that readers get bored.

One way to do that is to hide your descriptions in friction or conflict; as my example illustrates; Darcy is mildly irritated, Sheila is apologetic. The emotional "spice" hides that fact that we are bringing up once again that Sheila flies.

So Sheila flies over a mud bog without thinking, leaving Darcy to fend for himself. She accidentally whacks her head on a door frame. Invent problems with flying, she has to devise her own etiquette about flying to not offend her compatriots.

Comment: "Also recognize that both characters and the reader will grow accustomed to a character that is routinely flying, so you don't have to describe this often. Readers will get bored by the repetition, just like you do." Oh, this is such a relief to hear! It's also good advice.

Comment: @RHONDAHOWARD Thanks. Typically you should upvote any answers you like. Or any questions you like. Upvoting is free, it does not cost you any points. Like I upvoted your question.

Comment: I tried. I need 15 points to do that. Currently, I'm only at 11.

Comment: @RHONDAHOWARD Ah. I did not know that. Seems like a bug if a questioner cannot upvote the answers to their own question!